# numpy min and max functions return nan

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a two dimentional array full of floats representing the difference between two other 2D arrays.  I need to create a contour and map it, but when I try to map the contour I recieve an error stating that my contour needs at least 2 levels.

ValueError: Filled contours require at least 2 levels.
Error begins at a = np.min(tsEndAvg) and b = np.max(tsEndAvg)

```
 k = int(raw_input("Enter the iteration amount: "))*12
    x = 0
    # Appending Arrays to cover last 360th slot of lon
    lon2 = np.empty(len(lon)+1)
    for l in range(0, len(lon)):
        lon2[l] = lon[l]
    lon2[len(lon2) - 1] = 360.
    # Creating temp arrays for manipulation later
    tssum = np.empty([len(lat), len(lon)+1])
    tsEndSum = np.empty([len(lat), len(lon) + 1])
    ts2 = np.empty([len(lat), len(lon2)])
    time2 = np.empty(len(time))
    tsEndAvg = np.empty([len(lat), len(lon) + 1])

#START WHILE FOR BEGINNING DATA
    while x < k:
        print str(x)
        # x iterates through a slice of time, k is the iteration amount
        # Attempting to grab global sum of surface temperatures over k iterations
        ts = tempts[x, :, :]
        for i in range(0, len(lat)):
            for j in range(0, len(lon)):
                ts2[i][j] = ts[i][j]
        for i in range(0, 192):
            ts2[i][len(lon2) - 1] = ts[i][0]

        tssum = tssum + ts2# Running sum of the global data
        newDate = beginDate + datetime.timedelta(time[x])
        print newDate
        x = x + 1
    # Dividing each data point in tssum by k for the average amount
#END WHILE
    tssum = tssum / k

#START WHILE FOR END DATA
    x = len(time) -1
    while x > (len(time) - 1) - k:
        # x iterates through a slice of time, k is the iteration amount
        # Attempting to grab global sum of surface temperatures over k iterations
        print x
        ts = tempts[x, :, :]
        for i in range(0, len(lat)):
            for j in range(0, len(lon)):
                ts2[i][j] = ts[i][j]
        for i in range(0, 192):
            ts2[i][len(lon2) - 1] = ts[i][0]
        tsEndSum = tsEndSum + ts2
        x = x - 1
#END WHILE

# AVERAGING ALL GLOBAL DATA
    tsEndSum = tsEndSum / k
    tsEndAvg = tsEndSum - tssum
#END AVG   
    a = np.min(tsEndAvg)
    b = np.max(tsEndAvg)

    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection=c.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', linewidth=.25)
    ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)
    lon2, lat2 = np.meshgrid(lon2, lat)
    plt.contourf(lon2, lat2, tsEndAvg, levels=np.arange(a,b,1)) #ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE
    name = "SurfaceTempAnom-"+str(k/12)+".png"
    plt.savefig("/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/CESM/anoms/"+name, dpi=750, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
    print('saved: '+name)
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Comment: Your question title and question body seem to be different things. Are you asking why you're getting `nan` from `np.min` or `np.max` (in which case all the information about contours seems redundant, but we need to know how you calculated `tsEndAvg`), or are you surprised that using `np.arange(np.nan, np.nan, 1)` for your contour levels doesn't work? What's your question?

Comment: The error is that a and b are both nan when I'm trying to find the min and max values.  The weird thing is that when I run the file in the console at first it doesn't work, then when I use the np.min function on the same dataset in the console it works and returns an actual value.

Comment: Ah, you're using `np.empty`. The content of the generated array will be essentially indeterminate, and may or may not contain `NaN`s. You should double check that you really are writing into every slot of that array, and consider using `np.zeros` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, please show us your input data because it should work. See for example the minimal example:

import numpy as np
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
print np.max(a)

It will return 4. THus the most likely problems are:

- the input cant be interpreted as np-array
- its not a list/array of floats
- ...

Comment: my import data is from a netCDF file 
data = Dataset("netcdf-filename")

I updated the post with more code that shows more of the algorithm